# How to set lifecycle for bucket in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: python, google-cloud-storage

I want to change lifecycle of "my-bucket". I have this piece of code.

```
from google.cloud import storage

client = storage.Client(project='my-project')
bucket = client.get_bucket('my-bucket')
rules = {
            "action": {"type": "Delete"},
            "condition": {
                "age": 3
            }
        }
bucket.lifecycle_rules = rules
```

"bucket.lifecycle_rules = rules"
successfully set the lifecycle for bucket but somehow it didn't commit the change to remote side.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you change the properties, you need to submit those changes.

Try adding this line:

```
bucket.patch()
```

https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-python/stable/storage-buckets.html#google.cloud.storage.bucket.Bucket.patch

Answer (score 0):

You can also set lifecycle delete rules on your bucket as follows:

```py
# age is in days
bucket.add_lifecycle_delete_rule(age=175)

# .patch() is needed to push changes to gcp
bucket.patch()
```

Similarly you can also change the storage class:

```
# set storage to nearline after 3 days
bucket.add_lifecycle_set_storage_class_rule(age=3, storage_class='NEARLINE')
bucket.patch()
```

See also:
https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-enable-bucket-lifecycle-management